# Bulk Texture Baking of multiple models in Blender

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, texture-baking

Is there any way to bake the textures of the 1000s of buildings using any plugins or python scripts in Blender?

Each building has two models:

- High poly model and
- Low poly Model

I want the textures to be baked in bulk instead of selecting the 1st building - baking the textures of both high and low model and then repeating the same for the rest of the 1000 models. This gets tedious for manual work due to the quantity of models.

All bake setting are set for high and low poly models. I am looking for a solution that:

1. Selects the first building of both models(high and low) and bake the texture
2. Saves the textures on the hard disk and starts baking the next building models - both high and low.

-----_420 represent high poly model
-----_420.001 represent low poly model

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can write a Python script that loops through all objects in the collection, then selects the high-poly and low-poly, and bake an image texture. But you also need to make sure there is a bake target in the material for each object. Or you need to script that, too.

Comment: What do you mean by "baking" - exporting. Is this a simulation?
Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RumenBelev this question is about automated texture baking. It's described in the last paragraph. The screenshot shows the settings for baking the *Diffuse* color of the selected objects (high-poly to low-poly). But the question lacks a bit of info about the prepared(?) materials and what to do with the images. Is it enough to save only the images or should they be used in (new?) materials after baking?